# How to run fish file inside shell

Tags: shell, config, fish

How do I run `.fish` files inside the function folder in my directory?

Comment: The question lacks sufficient context or clarity to provide a meaningful answer. Providing more details, including an example of what you're trying to do, would help.

Answer (score 3):

If you have fish shell installed and your default shell is sh/bash you can do it simply with

```
/usr/bin/env fish /path/to/script.fish
```

That works both in command line or in bash scripts.

Alternatively you can change to fish shell from you default one and execute it from there.

To explain what the command means:

- `/usr/bin/env fish` - will locate fish executable based on your current environment PATH. After locating it it will be executed with all input after this line being passed as arguments to fish executable.

As another option you could simply find where your fish executable is and use `/path/to/fish /path/to/script.fish`

Third option would be to use `hash-bang` declaration in your script as first line `#!/usr/bin/env fish` and then make script executable (`chmod +x /path/to/script.fish`) so that your current shell would see that it needs to execute script with specified binary.

Comment: Thanks, also if I want to run a .sh file in terminal like an exec (not in fish), how can I do that? I try running it directly and it says permission denied, then I su run it and it doesnt do anything

Comment: @John exactly same way. This is universal method to execute some binary with given arguments. For example for Python scripts it would be `/usr/bin/env python`

Comment: @John To explain a little more - when you say "execute some script with fish", what you actually mean is "execute fish binary and pass path to script as an argument"

Comment: So all those forms of command basically execute fish binary and pass your script as an argument/stdin to it.